# Scheme-Wrong type to apply #f error in code for checking a prime number

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am writing a program to check if a number is prime in Scheme. However, I have written the following code. I check out another question on StackOverflow where the OP was getting the same error. I checked whether I was committing the same mistake. I was not. I have also checked all parantheses. They are perfect. Where can the error lie?

This is my code.

```
(define 
    (prime? x n)
        (cond ( 
            ( = 0 (remainder x n) (display "not prime") ) 
            ( = x (- n 1) (display "prime") ) 
            ( else (prime? x (+ n 1))) 
        )))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, there are problems with the parentheses. Also the logic seems off, you should test the second case first:

```
(define (prime? x n)
  (cond ((= x n) (display "prime")) 
        ((= 0 (remainder x n)) (display "not prime")) 
        (else (prime? x (+ n 1)))))
```

Use it like this, starting `n` with value `2`.

```
(prime? 17 2)
=> #t
```

Be careful though, if `x` is `1` it'll loop forever, you should handle that edge case separately.

Comment: I did try that!! It gave me an error. That was my first attempt!

Comment: These paranthesis really confuse me. Can you tell me a simple way to ensure that I have my paranthesis correct?

Comment: I'll try to correct the logic right now. If not, I'll modify the question.

Comment: I switched x and n in the second conditional statement.

Comment: @RohitShinde It's fixed now. Regarding the parentheses ... use a good editor that highlights them, and practice a _lot_ the simple expressions (say, a `cond`) before writing more complex programs.

Comment: @RohitShinde - Emacs modes like [paredit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit), [Auto Pairs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs), and the built-in `show-paren-mode` all help with paren matching. I'm sure `vi` has similar things.